# Basic New Action Testing ActionController::TestCase

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, testing, functional-testing

I am somewhat new to testing in rails, and I'm wondering if this is a sufficient test for my new controller.

```
test "should get new" do
  get :new
  assert_response :success
end
```

Controller:

```
def new
  @question = Question.new
end
```

Because the new action stores the controller in memory and does not write it to the DB, nor does it validate it. This seems sufficient to me. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Controller testing should generally assert a few things

1. Controller rendered the correct template
2. You redirected to the right place
3. The instance variable has the correct data

Sometimes I also send some extra post variables in to make sure someone isn't goin to be able to curl themselves into an admin.